# why python requests.get(url, stream=False) cannot get peer info

Tags: python, python-requests, python-responses

I am using requests.get on a hostname, and wanna to get to know peer IP and port. I did google and found this could be done only when we set stream parameter as True.
I am just curious, why stream as False cannot achieve this? Any design consideration?
I found the link "https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow" for stream, but not help here.

I played with code.

```
import requests
rsp = requests.get('https://xxx')
print rsp.status_code
print "rsp.raw type"
print type(rsp.raw)
print "_fp type "
print type(rsp.raw._fp)
print "_connection type"
print type(rsp.raw._connection)
print "_sock type"
print type(rsp.raw._connection.sock)
print rsp.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()
```

I found when stream is false, _connection is NoneType and exited. When stream is false, _connection type is "<class 'urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection'>" and getpeername() returns {ip,port}

Comment: Probably because `stream=False` reads the complete response and then *closes the connection*, whereas `stream=True` does not read the complete response yet and leaves the connection open…?!

Comment: @deceze Hi, yeah I saw this indication from doc. But I think "reads the complete response and then closes the connection", lib still is able to  attach the peer info, right?

Comment: It’s not info that’s guaranteed to be there. You’re accessing a `_protected` attribute there, which is simply something you do at your own risk and that’s not part of the officially sanctioned API. It *happens* to be there for internal implementation reasons in streaming mode.